# Importing stocker from Stocker

Tags: import, module, stock

```
!git clone https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis.git
!pip install quandl
!pip install pytrends
import stocker
from stocker import Stocker
```

I then get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-efeb5557f38a> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install quandl')
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install pytrends')
----> 3 import stocker
      4 from stocker import Stocker

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stocker'
```

New to all of this so not sure how to fix or what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the git clone portion but I managed to resolve with the following in Jupyter Notebook :

```
pip install stocker
import stocker
```

You can check if it works with this:

```
stocker.predict.tomorrow('AAPL')
```